# How to create different gap sizes for different items

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm working on a project and I have to get a gap of 12px between my list items and then a gap of 24px between everything else but for some reason no matter what I try it won't allow me to make a different gap. Please help I'm a very beginner and I'm on a time crunch

I'm working with flexbox stuff for my class i tried creating a flex container that sets the gap to 12px then creating separate sections parented by flex containers and setting the gap between them as 24px but it didn't end up working my teacher never actually taught us how to do this but she says we should know how so I'm very confused

Comment: please provide your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what your issue could be without seeing the code your working with, but if your looking for a brief rundown of the flex and gap properties here you go.

```
<!--sample html file-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Other stuff</div>

    <div>More stuff</div>

    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>

      <li>List item</li>

      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>

    <div>Other things</div>

    <div>More things</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside of our html file we have a number of div's and our linked list inside of the body tag.

In order to establish a gap of 24px between everything inside of body we'll need to set our gap property to 24px for the body.

Using flex as suggest in your post inside our .css file we add:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 24px;
}
```

By targeting `<body>` we can change our gap between each element inside the `<body>` to 24px.

Now in order to set a different gap for the items contained inside of our `<ul>` we'll need to target it in the same manor.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
}
```

Again adding this to our .css file will change the gap between our `<li>` items to 12px.